# Calling GetDesktopWindow() function in winuser.h instead of CWnd::GetDesktopWindow() in an MFC OnButtonClick function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

For my own education, I am playing around with the code snippets of some on-line examples.

Early in these examples, there are these lines:

```cpp
HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
```

For convenience reasons, I added a new button to my dialog-based demo MFC project, and the code I expect to test gets written into the `::OnBnClickedRuntest()` function.

This was working well in the past, with various other code snippets I studied, modified, and tested this way. For these lines, however, I get a **E0144** compile-time error:

> a value of type "CWnd *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "HWND"

I figured that I run into some sort of name-matching/visibility issue. As I am hoping to call `GetDesktopWindow()` and `GetDC()` defined in `winuser.h`, but apparently the `CWnd` class also has methods with these exact same names and different return types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdesktopwindow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#getdesktopwindow

Obviously, my test code being placed in the `OnButtonClicked` function of an MFC dialog, `GetDesktopWindow()` and `GetDC()`  prefers to call the `CWnd::GetDesktopWindow()` and `CWnd::GetDC()` methods, instead of the intended `winuser.h` functions.

**How do I clarify to the compiler that instead of the `CWnd` methods, I want to use the `winuser.h` functions of the same names?**

Comment: In MFC you can use `CClientDC dc(GetDesktopWindow());`. `CClientDC` calls `GetDC/ReleaseDC`. But calling core functions with resolution operator can be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the scope resolution operator on the functions:

```
::GetDesktopWindow();
::GetDC();
```

Comment: THAT IS WHAT I WAS MISSING! I knew that should the case be the other way around, I could force the use of the class methods by calling CWnd::GetDesktopWindow. What I did not know is the way to force the non-class function is to simply write the double semicolons. And I did not even know how to phrase this question for a search engine.

Comment: Ed, I had to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer. The portal did not allow me to do so before that.